# How to convert a string of utf-8 bytes into a unicode emoji in python

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, encoding, utf-8

So I have downloaded Facebook Messenger messages which are a couple of json files containing lots of information. Here's a snippet of the json:

```
"messages": [
{
  "sender_name": "sample name",
  "timestamp_ms": 1649215459023,
  "content": "sample message",
  "reactions": [
    {
      "reaction": "\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0086",
      "actor": "actor name"
    }
  ],
  "type": "Generic",
  "is_unsent": false
}
```

]

What I want to do is read this json and later create a dataframe with it, but since all the non-ASCII characters have been replaced with the `\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0086` type of code, it's not recognizing it as an emoji for example.

My question is, what do I need to do to be able to actually see those emojis as is, intead of those codes? I thought about using regex to find all of those patterns, but I don't know with what exactly I can replace them.

Comment: You might want to actually show how you download the message because it could be that code that is giving you this badly formatted JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I encountered the same problem when trying to decode a Facebook message dump. Here's how I solved it:

```py
string = "\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0086".encode("latin-1").decode("utf-8")
# ''
```

Here's why:

1. This emoji takes 4 bytes to encode in UTF-8 (`F0 9F 98 86`, check at the bottom of [this page](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F606/))
2. Facebook could have used UTF-8 for the JSON file but they instead chose *printable ASCII* only. So it encodes those 4 bytes as `\u00F0\u009F\u0098\u0086`
3. `encode("latin-1")` was a convenient way to convert these encodings back to the raw bytes.
4. `decode("utf-8")` convert the raw bytes into a Unicode character.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! You fixed my problem. Why do I need to encode it to "latin-1" first? Also I don't get the difference between \u00f0 and \xf0 for example.

Comment: @LucasJofre `latin-1` has the special property that it encodes each of the Unicode code points 0-0xff to the identical byte value.  `.decode` needs to start with a byte string anyway.  P.S. there's no difference between `\u00f0` and `\xf0`.

Comment: @LucasJofre see my edited answer