# Removing literal backslashes from utf-8 encoded strings in python

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8

I have a bunch of strings containing UTF-8 encoded symbols, for example `'\\u00f0\\u009f\\u0098\\u0086'`.
In that case, it represents this emoji , encoded in UTF-8. I want to be able to replace it to the literal emoji. The solution someone recommended to me was to encoded it into `latin-1` and then decode it to `utf-8`. So,

```
'\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0086'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
```

gives me the output

```
''
```

Unfortunately, all the strings with those codes have a literal backslash into them, so whenever I to do the same operations,

```
'\\u00f0\\u009f\\u0098\\u0086'.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
```

I get the following result,

```
'\\u00f0\\u009f\\u0098\\u0086'
```

Is there a way to remove those backslashes? Because if I replace them with an empty string, all backslashes disappear.

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading.  You don't just want to eliminate the backslashes, you want to convert the entire sequence that goes with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you're getting that string from, but it's an.... unusual... way of representing the codepoint. U+1F606 SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND TIGHTLY-CLOSED EYES is encoded in UTF-8 as the bytes `F0 9F 98 86`. In Python string escapes, `\uXXXX` is used to represent an entire codepoint in the Basic Multilingual Plane, and `\UXXXXXXXX` codepoints beyond it (Like this one), not a single byte of its UTF-8 encoding. So you'd expect to see it represented in a string as `'\U0001F606'`

Anyways, the following will extract the last two hex digits of each escape sequence, turn them into a byte array, and then decode the resulting UTF-8 data into a string:

```py
import re
str='\\u00f0\\u009f\\u0098\\u0086'
print(b''.join([ bytes.fromhex(m.group(1)) for m in re.finditer(r'\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{2}([0-9a-fA-F]{2})', str) ]).decode())
# Displays
```

Comment: From your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71790347/how-to-convert-a-string-of-utf-8-bytes-into-a-unicode-emoji-in-python), it sounds like you're getting this string from JSON supplied by facebook? The codepoint *should* be encoded as `"\ud83d\ude06"` in ASCII-only JSON and converted appropriately by any JSON parser.

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry if the question was misleading, it was a bit confusing to me to realize what I needed to do. Also, I get this data downloading from Facebook Messenger, it is a .json file with information like messages and reactions (emojis), which is why I it had a lot of codes like that one. Everything non-ASCII got converted to this weird code for some reason.

Comment: Maybe some mojibake happening somewhere in the pipeline.

Comment: @Shawn I don't think it's mojibake, I think that's the way JSON specifies complex Unicode characters to be encoded.

Comment: @MarkRansom No, that's not how JSON works. It uses one or two `\uXXXX` escapes per codepoint (two is a UTF-16 surrogate pair for ones outside the BMP)

Answer (score 1):

`b'\\u00f0\\u009f\\u0098\\u0086'` can be decoded directly by using encoding "unicode_escape".

For example:

```
>>> b'\\u00f0\\u009f\\u0098\\u0086'.decode("unicode_escape")
'ð\x9f\x98\x86'
```

Although it seems different, it's the same:

```
>>> b'\\u00f0\\u009f\\u0098\\u0086'.decode("unicode_escape") == '\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0086'
True
```

Beware that this will remove escaped backslashes on their own! For example, the following JSON will break:

```
>>> encoded_json = b'{"a":"Basic realm=\\"Dost\\udceapz"}'
>>> encoded_json.decode("unicode_escape")
'{"a":"Basic realm="Dost\udceapz"}'
>>> json.loads(encoded_json)
{'a': 'Basic realm="Dost\udceapz'}
>>> json.loads(encoded_json.decode("unicode_escape"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/javier/.pyenv/versions/3.6.15/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/javier/.pyenv/versions/3.6.15/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/javier/.pyenv/versions/3.6.15/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 20 (char 19)
```